# Voltage reversal circuit

Tags: voltage

My input is an SPST Dry contact with the closure of 0.5 seconds. I can energize the closure by 5 VDC if needed. The PCB runs on 5 VDC. I need to reverse the output voltage of the PCB to run two bistable valves. These valves are triggered by 5 VDC, +5 VDC for ON, and -5 VDC for off for 0.5 seconds.

I am familiar with the DPDT relay type "X" design but I need a solid-state solution. I also believe I need a flip-flop to control the sequencing of the pulses. Unlike other circuits for voltage reversal that control motors that spin and create Back EMF issues, this circuit should be much simpler.

Unfortunately, A little knowledge is a dangerous thing so I need some experienced advice. So 6 wires are needed on PCB, voltage in (5vdc), Trigger -- dry contact closure of 0.5 s and output of 5 VDC that is reversed polarity each time the dry contact is pulsed for 0.5 seconds.

The REVERSIBLE output is ON only on for the same 0.5 seconds and runs a set of valves that consume about 800 mA.

[image: System Overview image description here]

Comment: A circuit diagram or a picture would be helpful.

Comment: Sounds like you need a MOSFET H-bridge and some logic.  My approach might be to use a small microcontroller to give some intelligence, maybe monitor for UVLO and have some status LEDs, though you could do it with discrete components.

Comment: If the PCB runs on 5 VDC where does the -5 V come from? A schematic and timing diagram would be much better than many words.

Comment: Consider the DRV8844 Quad ½-H-Bridge Driver. Each  ½-H is a SPDT 2A switch <$4